# Visually inspecting NaNs in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I'm working with a complex dataset with hundreds, and sometimes thousands, of columns. Many of them are NaN, and systematically so (they tend to be highly correlated in the way the nulls are spread out). That leads me to believe that a visual inspection of NaNs is a good first start. I can do

```
dataframe.count()
```

to get the number of values present in each column, but I don't know their distribution.

So I want to make a scatterplot that visually mirrors the dataframe's layout, and the point is either colored in for NaN or left empty for a real value. That way I can see patterns of NaNs that tend to be clustered together. I don't know how to do this on matplotlib, though.

In other words, how can I plot

```
dataframe.isnull()
```

in a scatterplot, where the X axis is the labels, and the Y axis is the index?

Also, if you know of any other ways of inspecting for "patterns" of nulls in a dataframe, please share them with me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanted something more like a "scatterplot that visually mirrors the dataframe's layout"

you could try `matplotlib.pyplot.spy`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.spy(df.isnull())
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! A heat map is what I wanted

```
pcolor(df.isnull())
```